# Cmake error at Windows download Prebuilt Dependencies.cmake:54 file Download hash mismatch

Tags: python, windows, cmake, caffe

I'm trying to install Caffe for windows 8. I'm using [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) article for installation guide, I installed visual studio 2015. I put python.exe & CMAKE.exe on the path & after running these errors occured.
I appreciate any help.

[image: First]

[image: Second]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching my question,I understood maybe the problem is about "time out" in network connection or another problem about downloading.
I removed the complete binary output  `build` directory, again.

I used "freegate.exe" and tried again.

> cmd>cd caffe
>
> cmd>caffe>scripts\build_win.cmd

and it started downloding.